how can I clone or duplicate a work item query in azure devops?
I remember I used to do this but I don't see any way to "Save As", "Clone" or duplicate a work item query... ?  I remember doing this in the past...



To clone an Azure DevOps query:

Open the query
Click on Editor
Click on the 3 dots icon (top-right corner) and then Save As option
Enter the new query name and select the folder



Listing the cloned queries:


If someone from the Azure DevOps team reads this: I had to spend a few minutes trying to understand if it was possible to clone the query, and where that option is.
Why isn't the Save As button available in all menus where the Rename Query option is?
